# Is the GNU compiler that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 not compliant with C++ 11?

Tags: c++11, g++, ubuntu-12.04

Been having some problems with the Ubuntu 13.04 updates so I took down my Ubuntu 13.04 system and installed 12.04 LTS and the gnome shell, which is the look and feel I prefer.

I use Ubuntu mostly for C++ development and use C++ 11. My preferred IDE is CodeLite http://www.codelite.org/.

I installed CodeLite and added the C++ 11 compiler switches for the GNU g++ C++ compiler: ***-std=c++11***, as I did previously. (I have many projects that use C++ 11 and I can compile and build them fine on 13.04.)

But I can't compile a project using the compiler switch on 12.04. I get a an error message:

cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’.

Without the C++ 11, I can build and run a C++ project without problems.

**Is the GNU compiler that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 not compliant with C++ 11?** How do I fix this? I looked in Synaptic and didn't find any upgrades available. I have never tried it before on 12.04, but C++ 11 switch was working fine on 12.10.

**Am I stuck? How can I fix this so I can stay on 12.04 and use C++ 11?**

Comment: What is the full command you are using? Is it possible that you are passing -std into a subcommand as opposed to passing this option to g++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC versions prior to 4.7 use "-std=c++0x" instead of "-std=c++11" since the standard wasn't definitely C++11 at the time those versions were released. There are [C++11 features present in later GCC versions that will not be implemented on older versions](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). GCC 4.8.1 is the first release that is truly C++11 feature-complete.

I imagine you can update the compiler packages to something recent while keeping the majority of your Ubuntu install at 12.04.

Comment: It worked with c++0x. Meanwhile I'll have to poke around and see if I can upgrade to 4.8.1. Maybe you know where I can get a binary for debian? What am I missing out on? Anything?

Comment: @Vector The [GCC C++11 support status page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) will tell you what features are present in each version of GCC. [Here are instructions on installing GCC 4.8 in Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal). All hail Google.

Comment: you can now install 4.8 from that PPA - that post is 4 months old - at least I just did it and it installed.